# external css doesn't download in internet explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, styles, stylesheet

I have the folowing link to style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

It downloads great in every browser except IE11. In IE11 in console is shown the following problem:

> SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch.

But if I add a link from bootstrap website instead of previous one it works great in IE11, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Also I noticed that the problem disappears after commenting `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I checked "regedit.exe" and there everything was fine. Link is inside the header. Also I tried to copy code from website, save it again and so on but it doesn't work.

Comment: Load the page with a browsers network inspector running, find the request for the CSS document and see if its served with a content-type header of "text/css" - in not its a misconfigured server.

Comment: Alex, you are right. I don't have this content-type in inspector.                        The main problem is that I can use only this server which calls Ataccama. Is it possible to solve this problem anyhow?